# Android CleanArchitecture Domain module and AutoValue

Tags: android, auto-value, clean-architecture

i want to use clean architecuture in a new app and so far it works great. I structured the app into 3 modules (presentation, data and domain) like in the following example: [Android-CleanArchitecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture)

There are some entities in my domain module. One of them is User.

```
    public class User {

        private String name;

        public String name () {
            return name;
        }

        public static class Builder {
            ...
        }
    }
```

I want to use AutoValue with some extensions to get rid of boilerplate code. One of the extensions is [AutoValue Parcel](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-parcel). Now i need to implement the android.os.Parceable interface which is a part of android and can not be used in my domain module because it is a Android dependency.

What is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: I have the same question, may be we should use `java.io.Serializable`, but I prefer to use some library similar to https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-parcel.

Comment: Yes but i think in the end it will be better to make the domain module a android library.

Comment: AFAIK, Domain Layer shouldn't have any Android dependency, otherwise the testing will be difficult.

Comment: Yes i know. Thats why i am asking this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fulfilling the ideal of Clear Architecture is a bit hard with Android, as Android is a entire framework that has its own specification, even at basic language level.

I think, as the ideal of specific tools free level is mostly for testing purposes, thus - this should be the main goal in mind when dealing with Android.

Regarding the [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) itself, consider that it's merely adds additional methods for model object in order to make Android OS be able to serialize/deserialize data between different system components. So as your tests in the domain level doesn't run by Android OS, they should not touch this methods and it would not affect your tests.

Consider, several other APIs in Android that are not available in unit test, like [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html), [DateUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html), [SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) and more...
That's where I think that `Roboelectric`can come handy, with mocking these Android primitives.

Having said all that... with Clear Architecture, your Domain level should be separated from Presentation level, so basically you would have model objects in **both** layer (that can share interface) and both of them can use `AutoValue`, but, only in Presentation level you can implement the `Parcelable` interface (which are the ones that needs it, as in this level you'll interact with the System and use `Parcel`). 
No Android  dependencies in the Domain level are not the only consideration for this separation, bear in mind, that Presentation level might add information that is not relevant to Domain level.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So i will need to map the entities from my domain module (pure Java) to entities from my presentation module (Android). I assume the presenation module is responsible for this.